# extract the value of a column based on corresponding two other columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried

```
print(df.loc[df['A'] == 'A value', 'B'].item())
```

Which returns the value of B corresponding to A value.

But what if I wanted to do something like this:

```
print(df.loc[df['A'] == 'B' & df['C'] == 'C Value', 'Grade'].item())
```

I want the returned value to be a normal string without brackets.

Comment: Can you share some sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose I have dataframe which looks like this,

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

And I want to get the value of column `D` for all rows who have equal column `A` and `B` values and whose column `C` value is equal to 1, I can do this,

```
df.loc[(df["A"] == df["B"]) & (df["C"] == 1), "D"]
```